# Autoremounting of a SD card after unmount

Tags: ubuntu, mount, automounting, sd-card

I connected a SD card to my notebook, which got auto mounted by the Operating system.
After that I unmounted all the partitions, and wrote a modified raspian image directly to the device. Since new raspian images need a ssh file in their boot partition at startup I need to create one first.

So my Problem is now, that I want to mount to be system managed (like the automount) in case the SD card gets pulled out sometime. With a manual mount the mounting itself would still be listed, even if the device is not available any more.

Is there a way to accomplish this?